# Google app script library getScriptId() returns ID from calling script instance

Tags: google-apps-script

**Using Library**

I am using method `ScriptApp.getScriptId()` in my script A.
In script B, I have library imported from script A. 
When I call this library from script B, the method `getScriptId()` in A returns ID of script B intead of script A.

Is there a way to tell AppScript which instance to use?
I tried `ScriptApp.getScriptId(this)` and `ScriptApp.this.getScriptId()` but that's no good...

Thank you!

**Script A:**

```
function main() {
  Logger.log(getLib_ID());
  return 1; // **for testing only!**
  if (masterFile[i][mfId] === ScriptApp.getScriptId()) { // 
    ...
  }
}
function getLib_ID() {
  return this.id=ScriptApp.getScriptId();
}
```

**Script B:**

```
function test() {
  myLibrary.main();
}
```

Comment: @I'-'I: Thanks! I tried it and it still yields script-B ID.
I updated the original post with part of code...

Comment: I figured out a very simple workaround :-)
Script A function main(param 1, param 2, param 3) will take all necesary parameters directly from the call from script B...